# Pages often become unresponsive in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

In Windows XP, running Google Chrome, I often receive a message asking me to either kill the page or wait. I already reinstalled it, but the same problem persists.

I tried running it with `-no-sandbox`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: When you uninstalled Google Chrome, did you opt to have your Google Chrome profile deleted? Try using a [new profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059), and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Also, does it happen for all pages or just particular ones?

Comment: Does this happen often on pages requiring a specific plugin, such as Flash?  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Yeah, I Tried using New Profile, but the same problem persists.

All Pages, 

My computer specs; Intel P4 1.8GHz 1GB RAM VGA 64mb the remaining capacity at 5Gb system; I tried to intall chrome Offline & Online, but that's just the same

Answer (score 1):

If DropBox is running in the background then Chrome may have unresponsive pages.  Try removing DropBox from the Startup menu if you have this problem.

Comment: it's safe ? Ok, I'll Try it ... Thank's

Answer (score 0):

try updating Chrome and your OS (Windows XP).  Also ensure that your computer meets the minimum requirements for Chrome, and the pages you're browsing.

Comment: My computer specs;
Intel P4 1.8GHz
1GB RAM
VGA 64mb
the remaining capacity at 5Gb system;
I tried to intall chrome Offline & Online, but that's just the same,
What are the minimum specifications of my PC?

Comment: How much free disc space?